# How to use Laravel DI inside models?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5

I have an Eloquent model object: `$user`, of class `User`.

I want to make a method inside this model:

```
function sayHello($target)
{
    $this->hello = MegaFacede::launch();
}
```

Facades are not IDE friendly, so I get services from the container:

```
function sayHello($target)
{
    /** @var Mega $mega */
    $mega = App::make('mega');
    $this->hello = $mega->launch();
}
```

But how can I inject $mega instance to this object?

Comment: Do you mean `$this->hello = $mega->launch();`? A facade simply resolves the instance from the DIC for you and calls the method - the method itself isn't actually static.

Comment: Facades are fairly IDE friendly if you use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: Are you saying you want to put `sayHello` in your User model? Business logic doesn't belong in models; create a separate class for such things, and pass in your $user object to it if needed.

Comment: @Hailwood sure. Just a mistake.

Comment: @Ben it's not. I use it, but id doesn't solve all the methods.

Comment: @Ben I use Active Record models, and this pattern say that the models can have business logic. If I wanted business logic layer in services, I'd use Doctrine.